# Redirect to server route on ReactJS component using React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-v4

I have my React Router V4 routes structured this way:

```
const isAuthenticated = () => {
    let hasToken = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    if (hasToken) return true;
    return false;
};

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) =>
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
            isAuthenticated()
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <I NEED TO REDIRECT FROM HERE TO SERVER PAGE />}
    />;

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename="/editor">
                <Switch>
                    <AuthenticatedRoute exact path="/" component={AppNav} />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute
                        exact
                        path="/:module"
                        component={AppNav}
                    />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute
                        exact
                        path="/:module/:screen"
                        component={AppNav}
                    />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute
                        exact
                        path="/:module/:screen/:action"
                        component={AppNav}
                    />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute
                        exact
                        path="/:module/:screen/:action/:id"
                        component={AppNav}
                    />

                    <Route component={PageNotFoundError} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

As you see on code, if not authenticated I want to redirect to server page. The page is another react application to manage user registration and is located in the server but in another route tree: `/registration`

What I've tried with no success:

```
<Redirect to="//registration' />
windows.location = "/registration"
windows.location.href = "/registration"
<Redirect to="http//registration' />
windows.location = "http://registration"
windows.location.href = "http://registration"
```

All of the redirects to page in current application.

What would be the solution for this ?

Comment: Try to provide the whole url for example `window.location="https://your_website.com/your/server/path"`

Comment: Tried. Does not work.

Comment: do you get any errors? and make sure it's `window` not `windows`

Comment: Thanks for correcting. It ´s `window` indeed. No error. Move to `localhost:/editor/registration` or `localhost:/editor/https://registration`.Does not get out of App´s React Router.

Comment: First try `<Redirect to="/registration" />`. Maybe it's easier first to check for token and put this after render: `if (!hasToken) return <Redirect to='/registration' />;` and after <Switch> put <Route... without using <AuthenticatedRoute

Comment: Actually i tried what i have suggested and it works make sure to prepend the `http` protocol at the  beginning of your url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it like so:

```
const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) =>
    (<Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>(
            isAuthenticated()
                ? (<Component {...props} />)
                : ( window.location = "http://your_full_url" )
        )}
    />);
```

Comment: Works with external links (ex: `http://www.stackoverflow.com`, but does not redirect to own server. I´m getting the following error when redirecting to my own server - `window.location = "/login"`: `You are attempting to use a basename on a page whose URL path does not begin with a basename. Expected path "/login" to begin with "/editor"`. For sure the problem is related to the `<BrowserRouter basename="/editor">`...

Comment: I will accept this as an anwer and open a new issue related to basename.

Comment: Please share with us if you find any solution that's React-router based

Answer (score 2):

I had a create-react-app project with react router, and the problem that when entering a path '/path/*' it loaded the as if in the same react router, even though I had configuration for using another react project with an express server.
The problem was that the service worker was running in the background, and for any route inside '/' it was using cache.
The solution for me was to modify the 'registerServiceWorker.js', so that when you are inside the path, you ignore the service worker. I didn't get too deep in learning about service workers, but here is the code I used:

```
export default function register() {
    ...
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;
        if(window.location.href.match(/*\/path\/*/)){
           // Reload the page and unregister if in path
           navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
              registration.unregister().then(() => {
                  window.location.reload();
              });
           });
        } else if (isLocalhost) {
    ...
```

When inside the path, it unsubscribes the service worker and reloads the page.

Comment: Thank you! I struggled with this for far too long before realizing it was the service worker getting in the way.